# How to add System.Data.SqlserverCe.dll into my Windows Mobile 7.1 project in VS2010

Tags: windows-phone-7.1

I've installed SQL server compact 3.5 and I created database sdf. However, when I try to add System.Data.SqlServerCe.dll into reference. I see following error.[image]

there is no sqlservece.dll in .NET column, so I tried to every System.Data.SqlServerCE.dll files in C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server Compact Edition\v3.5 folder. But error message persists.

How to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You can only access SQL Compact with LINQ to SQL api on Windows Phone. If you want to include an existing database, that is possible. See my blog post here for details:

http://erikej.blogspot.dk/2013/04/generate-windows-phone-8-local-database.html